# Offline Auth Implementation

Tags: android, database, authentication, security, offline

I'm working on a fitness app that tracks the user's workouts , generates workouts, etc. It uses the Firebase API to authenticate the user when he has active network connection. The registration is done only through Firebase, and when the account is created, I store only locally his credentials.

If the device is offline, i use my custom offline auth to login the user. My offline auth process works like this:

- The user enteres his credentials (email and password), and the auth compares them with the ones stored locally (encrypted email and
  encrypted & hashed password inside a Room Db) .
- If a match is found, the app creates a session (a wrapper that holds the userUid , loginType (ex:Offline , Firebase - if it has network connection - and some other data required) and persists that session using Room.
- When the user enters again the app will look for the last session created(online login or registration will also create a session) in the table and load the information linked to that uid. The session will be removed from the db if the user signs out , deletes the account, changes email or password or if it is at least 1 month old.

I was wondering if it a viable solution to handle the RememberMe situation and if there were simpler ways to achieve that

Comment: Seams a bit over complicated, maybe some bit of information is missing or misunderstood by me. Why don't you just, after a successful online login, save the user-id in a table and use that ID for your offline session if next time the app is offline? Why bother with offline name/pw authentication? (Maybe the app is designed for several users, or local protection of fitness data in case the phone is used by someone else?)

Comment: I have not yet decided if i would allow multiple accounts stored on the same device , but you raised  a good point about over-engineering this :)) . If i decide to only allow only 1 account can I only rely on the Firebase.currentUser to provide the uid of the user? .